# Preventing global jQuery event on single form item

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my JS code loads I call the following which adds a `onkeypress` event to all text inputs:

```
$('#myForm input[type=text]').keypress(function(event) {
  sysOnEnter(event, $('#myForm input[type=text]').attr('id'), modalId);
});
```

The function `sysOnEnter` is to click a button when the user presses the `Enter/Return` key:

```
function sysOnEnter(event, id, modalId) {

  var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

  if (key == 'Enter' || key == 13) {

    var val = $('#' + id).val();

    setTimeout(function() {
      if ($('#' + id).val() == val)
        document.querySelector('#' + modalId + ' .btn-primary').click();
    },0);

    event.preventDefault();

    return false;
  }
}
```

The time that I **don't** want this to happen is when using Google's auto-suggest address form:

```
<input
  id           = "autocomplete"
  class        = "form-control"
  placeholder  = "Start typing..."
  onFocus      = "initAutocomplete();geolocate();"
  type         = "text"
  >
```

Is there an easy way to exclude this particular field from the javascript function?

Comment: If you add `:not(#autocomplete)` to your selector, it would exclude that particular input. More information: [`jQuery :not() selector`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). That said, what are you expecting the second parameter to be? `$('#myForm input[type=text]').attr('id')` will always return the ID of the first text input on the page.

Comment: I believe it's better to approach this different and instead give all your other inputs a class (like "selectOnEnter") and apply the event to all inputs with that class.

Comment: @Matt Yes I think that's a better idea!

Comment: @DanielWilliams It's a little more clear that way and it will allow you to easily give that functionality to other inputs, but also not confuse you when you come back a year from now and add a new field and wonder why it's doing something you didn't ask it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selector `:not(#autocomplete)` to exclude the element with the `autocomplete` id:

```js
$('#myForm input[type=text]:not(#autocomplete)').keypress(function(event) {
  console.log('firing event');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text" id="autocomplete" placeholder="autocomplete">
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the field you want to exclude is known beforehand you can use [JQuery .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('#myForm input[type=text]').not("#autocomplete").keypress(function(event) {
```